# Как создать мультисет пар в С++?

Tags: c++, операторы, multiset, приоритет

Мне нужно использовать multiset, но с использованием пар, объявляю я это так:

```
multiset <pair <int, int>> st;
```

Но затем, мне нужно смотреть на каждый элемент пары, я пытаюсь делать это так:

```
auto it = st.begin();
int a = *it.first;
```

Но что-то идёт не так, компилятор выдаёт ошибку

*error: 'struct std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<int, int> >' has no member named 'first'*

Подскажите, как мне достать первый элемент из пары?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приоритет оператора `.` (точка) выше приоритета разыменования. Поэтому

```
int a = *it.first;
```

трактуется как

```
int a = *(it.first);
```

а вам нужно

```
int a = (*it).first;
```

или, что то же самое,

```
int a = it->first;
```